# How to do division of groups in dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- tibble(year = c("2020","2020","2020","2021","2021","2021"), 
             website = c("google","facebook","twitter","google","facebook","twitter"), 
             category = c("big","big","small","big","big","small"), 
             value = c(10,20,30,40,50,60))
```

How can i calculate the change in the different between the years?

So for example i want to compare 2021 vs 2020, how can i do this in R?

for example the output should be something like this

| year | website | category | comparison |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 vs 2020 | google | big | 4 |
| 2021 vs 2020 | facebook | big | 2.5 |
| 2021 vs 2020 | twitter | small | 2 |

Where the column comparison is effectively value from current year/ value from previous year

I'm not too sure how to do this in dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pivot the year column to two different columns, and then use `mutate()` to calcualte `comparison`.

Here is an example:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = year) %>% 
  mutate(
    comparison = `2021`/`2020`
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   website  category `2020` `2021` comparison
#>   <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 google   big          10     40        4  
#> 2 facebook big          20     50        2.5
#> 3 twitter  small        30     60        2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can remove the extra columns with `select()` afterwards.

> Note: if your column is not called `value`, then you need to add this argument to `pivot_wider()`: `values_from = <your column name with values>`.

#### Update: If you want to keep your data in a long format

Just use `group_by(website)`, `arrange(year)` and `lag()` inside `mutate()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(website) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(
    comparison = value / lag(value)
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#> # Groups:   website [3]
#>   year  website  category value comparison
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 2020  google   big         10       NA  
#> 2 2020  facebook big         20       NA  
#> 3 2020  twitter  small       30       NA  
#> 4 2021  google   big         40        4  
#> 5 2021  facebook big         50        2.5
#> 6 2021  twitter  small       60        2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: What if i would like to keep it in a long format and just have the comparisons appear in the same year e.g. there is a comparison column and for row 2021 it would be all those values of 2021/2020 - for 2020 there would be NA as there is nothing to compare to?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(website) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  summarize(year = paste(year[2], year[1], sep = ' vs '),
            category = category[1],
            comparison = value[2] / value[1]) 
#>  A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   website  year         category comparison
#>   <chr>    <chr>        <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 facebook 2021 vs 2020 big             2.5
#> 2 google   2021 vs 2020 big             4  
#> 3 twitter  2021 vs 2020 small           2
```